# Oracle export problem

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
cmd:
exp bla/bla file=c:\bla.bkp
```

my bla schema in objects

```
Table
T_1
T_2
T_3
T_4

Functions
F_1
F_2

Procedure
P_1
P_2
```

I need all object but not in table ( **T_4** ) how to make ?

Comment: Please could you rephrase your question? Do you want everything except T4 or everything except objects whose names are contained in T4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the deprecated export utility, you cannot exclude a single object.  You would have to specify every table that you wanted in a TABLES clause, i.e.

```
exp username/password file=c:\bla.dmp tables=(T_1, T_2, T_3)
```

Obviously, that gets unwieldy rather quickly.  You can potentially write a query that generates the tables list for you and then copy & paste from a SQL*Plus window.  But that is also rather unwieldy.

Assuming you are using a reasonably new version of Oracle, however, you should be able to use the data pump version of the export and import utilities, expdp.  With expdp

```
expdp username/password dumpfile=c:\bla.dmp exclude=T_4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify teh tables of interest n the command line, something like

```
exp bla/bla file=c:\bla.bkp TABLES=(T_1,T_2,T_3)
```

Ok, that only gets tables, the rest of the stuff you are going to have to use/write something else.  Look at the `enter code here`dbms_metadata.GET_DDL procedure,

Comment: this code exp "bla/bla file=c:\bla.bkp TABLES=(T_1,T_2,T_3)" only tables i need all objects but not in "T_4" :-)